# Match JSON using RestKit using KVC Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I have this JSON (an array of dictionaries):

```
[
    {"id":"BTCLTC","last":"89.767","high":"96.185","low":"25.000","bid":"89.729","ask":"91.320","volume":"29.78918","scale":3},
    {"id":"BTCUSD","last":"443.799","high":"444.092","low":"394.570","bid":"439.110","ask":"446.760","volume":"4.68266","scale":3},
    {"id":"BTCXRP","last":"98101.500","high":"98101.500","low":"86000.000","bid":"94999.050","ask":"97499.900","volume":"21.66779","scale":3}
]
```

And I would like to use an `RKObjectMappingMatcher` to match against `"id":"BTCUSD"` for example.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Wain's comment below, using an `RKObjectMapping` was enough for KVC validation to work. The validation method is automatically called by RestKit.

My code thus far looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *defaultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:class];

NSDictionary *attributeMappings = [query objectForKey:@"attributeMappings"];
[defaultMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:attributeMappings];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dynamicMapping method:RKRequestMethodFromString(@"GET") pathPattern:@"/api/v1/markets" keyPath:@"" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful]];
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

I've added what I think is necessary for validation for an `NSObject`.

```
- (BOOL)validateCurrencyConversionID:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
{
    if ([(NSString*)*ioValue length] == 0)
    {
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:RKErrorDomain code:100 userInfo:@{@"description":@"Empty string"}];
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([((NSString*)*ioValue) rangeOfString:@"USD"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:RKErrorDomain code:101 userInfo:@{@"description":@"Doesn't contain USD"}];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use this approach, because you can't suitably index into the array and as a result you're processing an array where you expect a string.

Instead, allow the mapping to run for each and then use [KVC validation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation) to abort the mapping for the items you don't want.

Comment: Hi, can you comment on how I should fix the edited code above? I feel I'm not providing the proper mapping yet.

Comment: You don't need a dynamic mapping. Is your KVC validation working and rejecting unwanted items? You haven't shown validation of the id.

Comment: Thanks! My code is getting larger and so I forgot the attribute mappings by accident for this segment of code. Thanks again!